# Why some of my audits fail, should I report every issue?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Please, check the following screenshot:

[image]

[Here is the link to the review audit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6843504) I've chosen to `Close` this question, because we have exact reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You've done nothing wrong. It should be closed.

Comment: Audits are picked based on automated criteria; criteria in the *opposite direction* will invalidate a post. In this case, a downvote and a close vote would invalidate the post from being picked as an audit.

Comment: I've just closed the question. No idea why the system thinks it "looks good" possibly because of the upvotes.

Comment: @ChrisF: minimal number of upvotes + a minimal age, I think.

Comment: @ChrisF may I be unbanned then? I received 1 month ban for this.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov - I've unbanned you.