# Failed audit on question asking for documentation/book

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed an audit in the triage review queue on this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791362/how-to-get-started-with-perl-6
 ([link to review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9161820)) I flagged the post as Off-topic using this reason :

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I can see why some upvoters have found the question useful, but I fail to understand how it is on topic. I know that review audits are not hand-picked and that some of them may be mistakes, like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284505/why-some-of-my-audits-fail-should-i-report-every-issue).

Am I wrong in thinking that the question is off-topic? Why?

Comment: I'm with you....

Comment: also the bottom answer is a link only answer

Comment: Don't worry. Meta effect is coming.

Comment: @Pierre I often lurk in Meta-SO just to be a part of it ;)

Comment: The question is now closed.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: What's really odd is that this wasn't even a bounty question, which we've been having trouble with lately. I don't see why such an obviously bad question not only got up votes but didn't have any down votes.

Comment: The question got deleted now. Meta-effect done.